# devise react-rails registration form issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, customization, registration

I'm using Rails 4, Devise for auth, and React.JS for views via the react-rails on a project.

Currently am trying to get custom registration working. I followed the docs step by step, customized my routing to my User/registrations_controllers, and got everything working to the nitty gritty.

I'm using jquery to fire off the ajax from my form on the front end. Currently have hardcoded some data for testing.

I'm getting a 422 response now that says that it can't find password and email when I'm sending it. However, it does not mention anything about the other values passed in, so it seems like it's still going to the default devise engine... any help would be nice I know devise has a reputation for being difficult to configure.

Here's my controller function-

```
def create
     @user= User.new(configure_sign_up_params)
respond_to do |format| 
  if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
  else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

here's my strong parameters function-

```
 def configure_sign_up_params
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {|u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation) } 
 end
```

This is the data I'm sending after JSOn.stringify'ing-

```
 let formData =
        {
            "username": "test", // document.getElementById('username').value
            "password": "1234",
            "password_confirmation": "1234",
            "email": "test@gmail.com",
            "membership": "community"
        }
```

This is the error I'm getting on my network response- 422 with this body-

```
{"email":["can't be blank"],"password":["can't be blank"]}
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Try to send it as

```
{
  user: {
    "username": "test",
    "password": "1234",
    "password_confirmation": "1234",
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "membership": "community"
  }
}
```

since devise does something similar to `params(:user)` and it returns `nil` because there is no user key in parameters